# Numpy Implementation of Residual Student for Time Series

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, outliers

I'm trying to write a python function to calculate the studentized residual of a data-set. I tried to follow the traditional equation:

R_student(i) = e(i)/(std(i)*sqrt(1-hi))

where e(i) indicates the residual of the i-th datum, std(i) indicates the estimated value of the standard deviation without the i-th observation, h(i) is the i-th diagonal element in matrix H

X =

| 1 x1|

| 1 x2|

| 1 x3|

| .......|

| 1 xn|

H = X*(X^T * X)^-1 * X^T,

Where X^T is the transpose of matrix X

But the result is completely wrong. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have the following input/output data:

data = [26658, 29216, 30035, 30846, 29171, 21068, 28416, 25651, 22122,
       26423, 22467, 23274]

I know that the answer must be [-1.3053,  0.1031,  0.6535,  1.2399,  0.7552, -2.6869,  0.9257, 0.0968, -1.0527,  0.8846,  0.4535,  0.1101]

The code that I've wrote so far:

```
z = np.ones((len(data), 2))
z[:,1] = data

H = np.dot(np.dot(z, inv(np.dot(z.T, z))), z.T)

deviations = [data[np.arange(len(data))!=i].std() for i in range(len(data))]  
et = np.dot(data, H)

S =  (deviations * np.sqrt(1 - np.diagonal(H)))

rst = (data-data.mean()) / S

rst = np.array(rst)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
data-data.mean()
```

is not the correct definition of residuals [in this context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual#How_to_studentize). From your matrix `H`, you are fitting a linear model of the form `y=b0 + b1*x`. The correct meaning of residual is then:

```
y - y_hat
```

where `y` are the observations of the dependent variable from your data and

```
y_hat = np.dot(H,y)
```

are fitted values.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I tried to use y - np.dot(H, y) to calculate the residuals but I was not capable to arrive to the expected result. I'm trying to replicate the results from the paper: [Improved time-variant fuzzy time series forecast](http://ir.lib.isu.edu.tw/bitstream/987654321/9167/1/9167-1-springer.pdf). The definition of y - y.mean() for the residuals was from a doctoral thesis, that in theory get the results from the paper that I cited. I tried everything to try to replicate the results, but there is something that I'm not getting right.

Comment: Hmm.  There are two examples in that paper.  Have you successfully gotten the other example to work? If so, probably there is a mistake.  Either way, maybe you can email the authors and ask them for more information.

Comment: The other example doesn't worked either. I will try to email the authors.